# On wxWidgets Mac version (wxMac) where is the setup.h file I need to modify?

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets

I can't seem to find the right version of setup.h that gets used when building with ../configure, make. What directory is it? There seems to be tons of variations but I change them and the changes aren't used. Help.

Comment: Would the macports port of wxWidgets work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In the directory you built wxWidgets in, in the following path:

lib/wx/include/$CONFIGURE_SETTINGS/wx/setup.h

Comment: I want the setup file that is read to create the build not the setup that is created after.

Comment: Like passing --disable-choicedlg into ./configure ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be changing `setup.h` at all when using configure. Instead, rerun configure with the appropriate `--enable-xxx` options.

FWIW the previous answer by RyanWilcox does give the correct location of the file used but, once again, do *not* modify it directly.